# Regex: Extract capital letter out of camelCase

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to ask anyone more experienced in `regex` how they would finish my code so that it puts a space in front of each Capital letter that has lowercase letters in front and after it.

The code: `camelCase.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9][A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]/g, match => { return " " + match})`

Example:

`const camelCase = "thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace"`

`const wantedOutput = "this Should Be Separated By Space"`

`const currentOutput = "thi sShoul dBeSeparate dBySpace"`

Additionally, the regex should not catch an email address:

`const email = "this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com"`

`const emailOutput = "this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com"`

Thanks for any ideas! :)

Comment: `.replace(/(?!^)([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')`?

Comment: Match `(?<=[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]` and replace with a space and  $&

Comment: What should happen to `CheckABCDtest`?

Comment: @kv2016 ... `'thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace'.split(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/).filter(item => (item !== '')).join(' ')` ... and may you provide an example (input/output) which contains digits?

Comment: @JvdV This one wouldn't be modified. The use case is to separate camelCase words, but to ignore any Capital letters surrounded by special characters (anything else than [a-z0-9], such as an email address

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
  'thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace => ',
  'thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace'
    .split(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)/)
    .filter(item => (item !== ''))
    .join(' ')
);/*
console.log(
  'thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace => ',
  'thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace'
    .split(/((?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z][a-z0-9]*)/)
    .filter(item => (item !== ''))
    .join(' ')
);

console.log(
  'this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com => ',
  'this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com'
    .split(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)/)
    .filter(item => (item !== ''))
    .join(' ')
);
console.log(
  'this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com => ',
  'this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com'
    .split(/((?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z][a-z0-9]*)/)
    .filter(item => (item !== ''))
    .join(' ')
);*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

Since the OP did change the requirements one might write a specific sanitizing function that exclusively converts strings which do not feature any non word character ...

```js
function sanitizeValidCamelCaseString(str) {
  str = String(str);
  return (/\W/g).test(str)
    ? str
    : str
      .split(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)/)
      .filter(item => (item !== ''))
      .join(' ');
}

console.log(
  "sanitizeValidCamelCaseString('thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace') :",
  sanitizeValidCamelCaseString('thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace')
);
console.log(
  "sanitizeValidCamelCaseString('this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com') :",
  sanitizeValidCamelCaseString('this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter! However this one would separate strings including special characters (email, addresses, phone number), which is not what I want..

Comment: @kv2016 ... but you are aware that you changed your requirements just moments ago?

Answer (score -1):

I went with the following solution, which solves the problem. It matches any non-digit and non-letter characters, and processes camelCase into lowercase with Lodash's _.lowerCase(text), strings with special characters are processed with `String.toLowerCase()`.

```js
function format(text) {
  const specialCharacter = text.match(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/g);
  if (!specialCharacter) {
    return _.chain(text).lowerCase().trim().value();
  }
  else {
    return text.toLowerCase().trim();
  }
}

console.log(
  "format('thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace') :",
  format('thisShouldBeSeparatedBySpace')
);
console.log(
  "format('this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com') :",
  format('this.Is@NotSupposedToConvert.com')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: does this mean, you changed the requirements again and now you expect ... `'this should be separated by space'` ... instead of what was expected before ... `'this Should Be Separated By Space'`? Shall I update my already provided solution accordingly and again which does all this with a much smaller footprint?